# Golang, multiple commands in the same SSH Session

Tags: go, ssh

I need to run multiple commands in the same SSH Session. Between each command I'm sending. I need to parse the output.

I found I can printout the first line from STDOUT, but when I try and print everything it just hangs, seeming waiting for STDOUT. This works for printing the first line, I can't figure out how to print all from STDOUT and release back to the program to run the next command.

I need to run a command, parse the output, then run a second command within the same session.

Example of my code.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    // SSH credentials
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "rob",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("OMGAPASSWORD....EEEEEEE"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    // Connect to SSH server
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "*************:22", sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Open a new session
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Set up input and output streams
    sshIn, _ := session.StdinPipe()
    sshOut, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
    //sshErr, _ := session.StderrPipe()

    // Start the SSH session
    if err := session.Start("/bin/bash"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start SSH session: %v", err)
    }

    // Send the first command
    cmd1 := "ls -al"
    fmt.Fprintf(sshIn, "%s\n", cmd1)

    lines := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(sshOut)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(lines)
    }()

    for line := range lines {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: You only appear to be reading a single line, where do you expect to get the rest of the output?

Comment: Jim, I believe ReadString is just giving me the first line. But if I output all of the data from STDOUT. Then when I perform a print it just sits and doesn't ever go to the next command.

Comment: How are you trying to output "all the data from STDOUT"? There is no "all", because it's a stream, it doesn't end until the session commend exits.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. When I perform a loop it prints out all the lines and just hands at the end of the stream. Is there anyway I can identify I've reached the end of it?

Comment: End of what? There is no end until your command exits. You are trying to use an interactive shell, so you need to parse the output like a user would interactively. Basically you are trying to implement [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: My issue with expect is, I don't like managing timeouts. As some printouts can take various times to return. I agree what I'm trying to do here is almost exactly like expect.

Is there anyway to view the latest of everything in STDOUT, then run the next command?

Comment: Reading from stdout will return the latest from stdout, I don't understand what the question is. It doesn't matter how much time it took, you read until you get the output you want. If you want to handle timeouts, deal with the read loop concurrently, and generate output tokens via a channel.

Comment: I must not be reading from stout correctly. When try and loop over it, it gets to the end of the stream and doesn't print anything else. The program just sits and doesn't return anything more. 

I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Like I said above, you need to _parse_ this as if you were an interactive user, meaning you're not waiting for the end of the stream, you are waiting for some indication in the output, like a command prompt, to know it's time to type a new command. Continually reading in a loop must always eventually block, because the output is not going to end until the command exits entirely.

Comment: One problem you may have (you still did not show what your read loop looks like) is if you are using `ReadString('\n')`, the last output may not end in a newline which could block.

Comment: I added my loop, but I don't ever seen to get the command prompt back in STDOUT

Comment: You are using a line scanner, so it will block just like `ReadString('\n')`. You can't scan for lines if you are looking for something which doesn't end in a newline (I guess you could put a newline in `PS1`  if you wanted though). You're also not going to get a prompt without a pty, see the example in the docs: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#example-Session.RequestPty

Answer (score 2):

```
session.Start("/bin/bash")
```

Trying to run sequential commands through a persistent shell is the root of all your difficulties.  Since bash is what you're reading to and writing from, you can't easily tell when each command is successful.

Instead, start a new session with each command.  Copy stdout and stderr to buffers, then you can do whatever you want with them.

```
    for _, cmd := range []string{"ls -al", `bc <<<"3/2.0"`} {
        session, err := client.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
        // Set up input and output streams
        //sshIn, _ := session.StdinPipe()
        sshOut, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
        sshErr, _ := session.StderrPipe()
        go io.Copy(&stdout, sshOut)
        go io.Copy(&stderr, sshErr)
        // Start the command
        if err := session.Start(cmd); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to start SSH session: %v", err)
        }
        if err := session.Wait(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("error waiting: %w", err))
        }
        session.Close()
        fmt.Printf("Command: \t%s\nStdout: \t%s\nStderr:%s\n", cmd, stdout.String(), stderr.String())
    }
```

This way you know when each sequential command ends and whose output is which.

[Full example](https://go.dev/play/p/B2E4OD6uIie) should work locally if you have an ssh key pair in `~/.ssh`, but doesn't work in playground because there's no SSh server to connect to (or key pair).  Start a local ssh server like this:

```
docker run --rm -d -e PUBLIC_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"  -e USER_NAME=$(whoami) -p 2222:2222 linuxserver/openssh-server
```

Comment: I like this idea. But the main issue I have is that I HAVE to run them through the same session.

Comment: would you say more about that, if only to convince us that it's not an XY problem?  I'm also genuinely curious

Comment: Could be a XY problem, but the software I’d be parsing has to have the commands ran within the same session. It loads a set of proxies, and they change at each login

Comment: an ssh session is not the same thing as an ssh login

Answer (score 1):

The main thing missing is that you need to read again from the keyboard when your final loop blocks so you can send more commands to `stdin`.

Something like this:

```golang
// Last block of your code
for {
    fmt.Println("$")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    text := scanner.Text()

    wr <- []byte(text + "\n")
}
```

Another important part missing is the goroutine that will keep receiving commands from the OS scanner above, and will write that to the `stdin`.

```golang
// You need to create a gorouting to write to stdin
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case d := <-wr:
            _, err := stdin.Write(d)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

These two blocks should allow you to enter commands one after another.

Basically you'll need:

1. goroutine that writes to SSH stdin
2. goroutine that reads from SSH stdout
3. goroutine that reads from SSH stderr
4. A loop to block and read new commands from the `os.Stdin`

I've found [this functional gist](https://gist.github.com/21Quincy/2548ed990c01dd42c8886e83ab04f222#file-main-go) example that you can copy and run to use as a starting point.